# How to load assembly at runtime which has reference to another assembly

Tags: vb.net, dll, reference, runtime

I'm developing a extensible software with **WPF/VB.NET** which loads dlls from a extensions folder and create instances of them and add usercontrols from them. But in a certain extension I have to add reference of an another assembly and when I load that it doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Where is the "other assembly"?

Comment: See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies). If your other assembly is in the GAC then you will have no issue (so it's not). You can always handle AssemblyResolve event and use method 4 *Locating the Assembly through Probing* to point to the file if you know where it is.

Comment: It'a Windows.md reference. The extension needs reference to WinRT so I have to add Window.md as reference when I load the extension.

Comment: It works fine dude thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

My project load assemblies (ie. extension assemblies) from a local **Extensions** folder but the assemblies which are referenced by extension weren't. This code solves the issue of loading **reference assemblies of extensions** (hurray!) and some are resolved by GAC

included in Application.vb

```vb
Private WithEvents Domain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain

    Private Function DomainCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ResolveEventArgs) As Assembly Handles Domain.AssemblyResolve
        If e.Name.Contains(".resources") Then
            Return Nothing
        End If
        If Not IO.Directory.Exists(".\ExtReferences") Then
            IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(".\ExtReferences")
        End If
        Dim _Assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(Function(a) a.FullName = e.Name)
        If _Assembly IsNot Nothing Then Return _Assembly

        Dim filename = e.Name.Split(",")(0) + ".dll".ToLower()

        Dim asmFile = IO.Path.Combine(".\", "ExtReferences", filename)

        Try
            Return Assembly.LoadFrom(asmFile)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

I also came up with a particular case where a extension required access to WinRT :(

included in .(vb/cs)proj file

```xml
<Reference Include="System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Windows">
  <HintPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17763.0\Windows.winmd</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Thus all of my problems resolved!